# SQL JOIN all tables from one data

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get all the data from all tables in one DB.
I have looked around, but i haven't been able to find any solution that works with my current problems.

I made a C# program that creates a table for each day the program runs. The table name will be like this tbl18_12_2015 for today's date (Danish date format).

Now in order to make a yearly report i would love if i can get ALL the data from all the tables in the DB that stores these reports. I have no way of knowing how many tables there will be or what they are called, other than the format (tblDD-MM-YYYY).

in thinking something like this(that obviously doesen't work)

```
SELECT * FROM DB_NAME.*
```

All the tables have the same columns, and one of them is a primary key, that auto increments.

Here is a table named tbl17_12_2015

```
ID  PERSONID    NAME    PAYMENT     TYPE    RESULT  TYPE

3   92545       TOM         20,5    A       NULL    NULL
4   92545       TOM         20,5    A       NULL    NULL
6   117681      LISA        NULL    NULL    207     R
```

Here is a table named tbl18_12_2015

```
ID  PERSONID    NAME    PAYMENT TYPE    RESULT  TYPE

3   117681      LISA        30      A       NULL    NULL
4   53694       DAVID       78      A       NULL    NULL
6   58461       MICHELLE    NULL    NULL    207     R
```

What i would like to get is something like this(from all tables in the DB):

```
PERSONID    NAME    PAYMENT     TYPE    RESULT  TYPE
92545       TOM         20,5    A       NULL    NULL
92545       TOM         20,5    A       NULL    NULL
117681      LISA        NULL    NULL    207     R
117681      LISA        30      A       NULL    NULL
53694       DAVID       78      A       NULL    NULL
58461       MICHELLE    NULL    NULL    207     R
```

Have tried some different query's but none of them returned this, just a lot of info about the tables.

Thanks in advance, and happy holidays

edit: corrected tbl18_12_2015 col 3 header to english rather than danish

Thanks to all those who tried to help me solving this question, but i can't (due to my skill set most likely) get the UNION to work, so that's why i decided to refactor my DB.

Comment: I think you need to rethink your design. SqlServer is relational, why would you be creating all these new databases instead of just using datestamps and ids?

Comment: What do you mean by "all the data from all tables in one DB"? Do you perform some kind of aggregation for these data? All the data from all table virtually means the whole database :)

Comment: @ regerory Figured it would be better to have specific tables for each day, rather than one big that can stretch over years.
@Alexei True, i man i want all the data from the DB :)

Comment: Oh my god. That is some weird design. I want to tell you that you are in a big trouble. You should refactor this definitely. You will not be able to complete your job with this structure. How on earth you did come up with this solution?

Comment: Well tbh, i don't know better

Comment: @NicolaiSvendsen, believe me. You will not get answer here and anywhere else in universe to solve this except of advises to refactor. So take a deep breath and just refactor your schema. You have to do this.

Comment: Agreed - anyone offering dynamic SQL to deliver what you're asking for is hurting you more than helping.  Bite the bullet - it'll be easier now than later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you could store the table names in a database and use dynamic sql to union them together, this is NOT a good idea and you shouldn't even consider it - **STOP NOW!!!!!**

What you need to do is create a new table with the same fields - and add an ID (auto-incrementing identity column) and a DateTime field.  Then, instead of creating a new table for each day, just write your data to this table with the DateTime.  Then, you can use the DateTime field to filter your results, whether you want something from a day, week, month, year, decade, etc. - and you don't need dynamic sql - and you don't have 10,000 database tables.

I know some people posted comments expressing the same sentiments, but, really, this should be an answer.

Comment: I am under the impression the auto incremented ID is the same between records.

Comment: An auto incremented ID cannot be the same - it's impossible.  But, if you're talking about him having the ID in multiple tables - that problem will be fixed once he imports his data into his new table (and they are assigned a new ID).  He may have to adjust some foreign keys, but judging from his database structure, I'm guessing he doesn't have any.

Comment: @Stan This is the first work i do with SQL, so i think ill just follow your example. Thank you for the information.

Comment: @NicolaiSvendsen glad to help - and best of luck.  The fix isn't that hard - and will pay off huge for you in the future.  Please remember to accept and upvote the answer that helped you the most - and best of luck!  If you have any more questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: The term `timestamp` may be misleading here, as it has a different meaning in SQL Server than a "datetime stamp".

Comment: @Lucero correct - especially for a SQL beginner.  I've edited my answer.

Comment: I assume you mean making a column with the date where the record was added? :)

Comment: Yes, but you should use a DateTime datatype instead of Date.  That way, you can report on times at a later date.  And if you don't care about the times, you can just cast the DateTime as a date ==> CAST(DateTimeField as date)

Comment: Well as for now a Date will do fine, don't think that amount of precision is required for what i do ^^

Comment: If you make it a date now - you won't be able to add the time later.  Conversely, if you use the datetime and don't need it, you're unaffected.  Use the datetime.  Trust me :)

Comment: Will do then, and thank you for you'r passionate effort to learn me the right way :)

Answer (score 0):

If you had all the tables in the same database you would be able to use the UNION Operator to combine all your tables..

Maybe you can do something like this to select all the tables names from a given database

For SQL Server:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_CATALOG='dbName'
```

For MySQL:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='dbName'
```

Once you have the list of tables you can move all the tables to 1 database and create your report using Unions..

Comment: All the tables are in the same DB

Comment: You can then use a UNION to select all the data

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a UNION between each select query.

Do not use *, always list the name of the columns you are bringing up.

If you want duplicates, then UNION ALL is what you want.

If you want unique records based on the PERSONID, but there is likely to be differences, then I will guess that an UPDATE_DATE column will be useful to determine which one to use but what if each records with the same PERSONID lived a life of its own on each side?

You'd need to determine business rules to find out which specific changes to keep and merge into the unique resulting record and you'd be on your own.

What is "Skyttenavn"? Is it Danish? If it is the same as "NAME", you'd want to alias that column as 'NAME' in the select query, although it's the order of the columns as listed that counts when determining what to unite.

You'd need a new auto-incremented ID as a unique primary key, by the way, if you are likely to have conflicting IDs. If you want to merge them together into a new primary key identity column, you'd want to set IDENTITY_INSERT to OFF then back to ON if you want to restart natural incrementation.

Comment: Added a few words about auto id.

Comment: Skyttenavn is the same as name yes, just forgot to change it :) Or accyatly its ShooterName :)

Comment: Isen't the problem with UNION that you need to know how many tables there are, and what they are named?

Comment: Without dynamic SQL, yes - but with it, you can use variables to populate the names of the tables.  Regardless, you need to stop thinking about ways of retrieving data from this structure - and start thinking about fixing the structure.

Comment: UNION is very forgiving. The order of the columns is what matters more than the naming and, of course, they have to have the same data type.

Comment: Also... Stay away from dynamic SQL as much as possible. This prevents the execution plan from being cached.